# I am unable to use CORS in my MERN app, how to fix this?

Tags: cors, mern

I'm trying to build my first MERN project and encountered the dreaded CORS error in Chrome when I tried to fetch something from the Backend through the React. I tried using the CORS npm package but it doesn't seem to be able to fix the issue. This is the index.js of the Express application. I've also tried using CORS in the 2 routers separately, even that didn't work.

How to fix this? Thanks in advance!

```html
const express = require("express");
const memberRouter = require("./routers/Members");
const noticesRouter = require("./routers/Notices");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const cors = require('cors');

//Setting up express server
const app = express();

//Accept JSON request body
app.use(express.json());

//CORS call
app.use(cors());

app.listen(port, ()=> console.log('Server is up on port ' + port));
//Using the router for Members
app.use(memberRouter);
//Using the router for Notices
app.use(noticesRouter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Setting up express server
const app = express();

//CORS call
app.use(cors());

//Accept JSON request body
app.use(express.json());
```

Try moving the cors middleware before the `express.json()` middleware. Express middleware are executed sequentially, so the order in which they are added matters. Cors should usually be one of the first middleware you add to your express server, unless you are using the [helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) middleware, which I suggest you do because helmet sets a lot of headers that mitigate alot of security issues. It's recommended to use with express as per [express's docs](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html#use-helmet).

Comment: I think my problem was not because of CORS but because of the incomplete url I provided (omitted http://). I read up about helmet and will use it , seems like a no brainer. Thanks!